# Trigger polymer iron-ajax request manually

Tags: javascript, polymer

```
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('options-changed', function () {
        document.getElementById('getContent').generateRequest();
    });
```

The example above works perfectly fine. But as soon as I try to use `generateRequest();` in a custom element nothing happens. No Errors.

```
Polymer({
        is: 'vplan-table',

        properties: {
            options: {
                reflectToAttribute: true,
                notify: true,
                observer: '_optionsChanged'
            }
        },
        _optionsChanged: function() {
            //generateRequest not working!
            document.querySelector('#getContent').generateRequest();
            console.log('options changed');
        }
    });
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Have you tried using `this.$.getContent.generateRequest()` instead of `document.querySelector('#getContent').generateRequest()`?

Comment: That works fine. Thanks a lot! But mine is working too. I simply forgot to delete the old ajax code from the main page. The request worked but the databindings didn't. So this was my own dumb mistake.

Comment: I'd recommend you to use the code I mentioned because if you use `querySelector` directly on `document` in a Polymer element's code it might not work as expected if you use multiple instances of the same element at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alan's solution works! Use `this.$.getContent.generateRequest()` instead of `document.querySelector('#getContent').generateRequest()`. Thanks a lot [Alan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5021751/)!